# Apache not redirecting to index.php properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have an application and the entry point is index.php in /var/www/html/quote directory. The application is using slim framework to deliver json api. So I tested the application using php -S localhost:8080 but now I'm ready to upload to my hosting service so I want to be able to test the app by typing localhost/quote. I enabled mod_rewrite in apache2. Also I added this to the directory where index.php is localted
.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

finally, I modified the apache2.conf file and change  directive like this. changing AllowOverride to All

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now when I type http://localhost/quote. I'm getting "page not found"
what am I missing?

Comment: Try changing to `RewriteRule ^ /quote/index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman no didn't work..

Comment: What is the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of that http host?